# Adding javascript to html 5 head tag without using deprecated attributes

Tags: javascript, html

I'm going strictly HTML 5 here with my code and it doesn't work without adding deprecated attributes "type" and "language" within script.

Isn't "type" deprecated? Why did I read that HTML 5 input elements introduced several new values for the type attribute?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
   <head>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
         
         function showResult() {
            x = document.forms["myform"]["newinput"].value;
            document.forms["myform"]["result"].value = x;
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   
   <body>

      <form action = "/cgi-bin/html5.cgi" method = "get" name = "myform">
         Enter a value : <input type = "text" name = "newinput" />
         <input type = "button" value = "Result"  onclick = "showResult();" />
         <output name = "result"></output>
      </form>
        
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `type` and `language` are not tags. They are attributes. `type` is not deprecated but the default is javascript so it's not needed if that's what you're using. Yes, there are new attributes for the `<input>` tag.

Comment: When you want to know such things, consult [the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/) or search [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) Note that the `<input>` element does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: @Rob I know they're attributes, the 'head' element is a tag. Why when I search up deprecated attributes on HTML 5 does it show 'type' listed there, i.e [Source 1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_deprecated_tags.htm), [Source 2](https://dev.w3.org/html5/pf-summary/obsolete.html). I couldn't find anything on web docs prior to posting here about it. You mention the default is javascript, but I can't get it to work without using 'type'.

Comment: The `type` attribute is not deprecated on `<script>`. It's obsolete or deprecated on other tags. "Doesn't work" is not a technical description of a problem. What doesn't work?